# Hyphen between columns in a form

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a form using bootstrap, and I want it to be perfectly aligned, like this one

[image]

I have this structure:

```css
.w100x100 {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<form class="form-inline" method="get" action="index.php">

<div class="form-group col-md-10">
    <div class="input-group w100x100">
        <select class="form-control" name="myform">
             <option>Option</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<br>

<div class="form-group col-md-5">
 <div class="input-group w100x100">
  <input class="form-control" placeholder="input text"></input>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-5">
 <div class="input-group w100x100">
  <input class="form-control" placeholder="input text"></input>
 </div>
</div>
```

and is working fine, except for that I don't know how to put a hyphen between both inputs. I don't know what else to try.

Any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many trial and errors, I found a solution. It's so simple that I don't know how I didn't see it before.

I put this div between the columns:

```
<div class="guion">-</div>
```

And make it float to the left.

```
.guion {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're using Bootstrap.  So, could minimize it down to `<div class="float-left">-</div>`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a div between the two forms which contains a hyphen and give it say 10% then the other two divs you already have 45% each.